# How do I fix a run build?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, build, node-modules

I changed the versions of node js, I searched the internet. The only thing I found out: webpack was updated to a new version of ssl, I reloaded the packages, but it didn't help me. Problem with the web part

[image: full log]
[image: full log2]
[image: full log3]

```
[2] C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:133
[2]             if(isError) throw e;
[2]                         ^
[2]
[2] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
[2]     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
[2]     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
[2]     at module.exports (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
[2]     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
[2]     at handleParseError (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
[2]     at C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
[2]     at C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
[2]     at C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
[2]     at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
[2]     at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
[2]     at C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
[2]     at context.callback (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
[2]     at makeSourceMapAndFinish (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:90:5)
[2]     at successLoader (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:68:9)
[2]     at Object.loader (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:22:12)
[2]     at LOADER_EXECUTION (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:119:14)
[2]     at runSyncOrAsync (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:120:4)
[2]     at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)
[2]     at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
[2]     at Storage.finished (C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
[2]     at C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
[2]     at C:\Users\111\Desktop\drp\diamondrp-main\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
[2]     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
[2]   opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
[2]   library: 'digital envelope routines',
[2]   reason: 'unsupported',
[2]   code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
[2] }
[2]
[2] Node.js v17.0.0
[2] npm run build:web exited with code 1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem has been solved. The installation of node js v16 helped